# how to get rtsp url using onvif in ip camera android

Tags: android

I use OnVif java library but it is not working.

```
try{
    OnvifDevice nvt = new OnvifDevice(cameraIpAddr,cameraUsername,cameraPassword);
    List<Profile> profiles=nvt.getDevices().getProfiles();          
    String profileToken=profiles.get(0).getToken();
    String url= nvt.getMedia().getRTSPStreamUri(profileToken);
    PtzDevices ptzDevices=nvt.getPtz();
    org.onvif.ver10.schema.FloatRange 
    panRange=ptzDevices.getPanSpaces(profileToken);
    org.onvif.ver10.schema.FloatRange tiltRange= 
    ptzDevices.getTiltSpaces(profileToken);
    float zoom=ptzDevices.getZoomSpaces(profileToken).getMin();
    float x=(panRange.getMax() + panRange.getMin())/2f;
    float y=(tiltRange.getMax() + tiltRange.getMin())/2f;
    if(ptzDevices.isAbsoluteMoveSupported(profileToken)){
        ptzDevices.absoluteMove(profileToken,x,y,zoom);
    }
}catch (ConnectException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}catch (SOAPException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

In Android Studio, `SOAPException` class not found, i add class using external jar but gradle build fail for SOAPException please give me `onvif client` example for java or android then inform me.

Please give me reference for get rtsp url using online for android

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/yourfilename.jar')
}
```

Comment: OnvifDevice nvt = new OnvifDevice(cameraIpAddr,cameraUsername,cameraPassword);
Always crash app.